# React Native TouchableOpacity not working with position absolute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity

I have a list that shows results matching the user's input. The onPress of the touchableOpacity is not working in this list. This list is positioned absolutely and positioned below its parent view (positioned relative). The only time I can get the onPress to work is when I remove the `top:48` style from list and the onPress works for the single element which is directly onTop of the parent.

```
export default function IndoorForm(props) {
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.parent}>
        <Autocomplete
          style={styles.autocomplete}
          autoCompleteValues={autoCompleteValues}
          selectedLocation={props.getDestination}
        ></Autocomplete>
      </View>
    </View>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    top: Platform.OS === "android" ? 25 + 48 : 0 + 48,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width - 30,
    zIndex: 500
  },
  parent: {
    position: "relative",
    flex: 1,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#AA2B45",
    height: 48,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 16,
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  }
}

export default function AutoComplete(props: AutoCompleteProps) {
  const { autoCompleteValues } = props;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={autoCompleteValues}
        renderItem={({ item }: { item: POI }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("Haal")} key={item.displayName} style={styles.list}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.displayName}</Text>
            <Entypo name={"chevron-thin-right"} size={24} color={"#454F63"} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    flex: 1,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width - 30,
    top: 48,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#F7F7FA",
    backgroundColor: "#F7F7FA",
    zIndex: 999
  },
  list: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    borderBottomColor: "rgba(120, 132, 158, 0.08)",
    borderBottomWidth: 1.4,
    zIndex: 999
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you set your parent element (container) absolute to your child element  (parent) ? 
Try giving your elements background color to see what they cover on the screen so you can make sure your touchableopacity wraps around the list elements.

Comment: The parent has absolute because it is on top of a mapview component. So I position it absolutely so it can be ontop. My touchable element has a background color and border already. The issue is I can move the map behind the touchable when I move my finger on the touchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this by dynamically adjusting the container height so that the touchableOpacity is within the container. The issue was I positioned the list outside of the parent (as intended by styling) but for onPress to work it has to be inside the parent.

```
  let autocompleteHeight = autoCompleteValues.length * 65

<View style={[styles.container, {height: autocompleteHeight}]}>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know you solved your issue already, but you can use this magical library `react-native-gesture-handler`, import your `Touchable`s from there and they don't care about being inside the parent views. You can touch them regardless.

Comment: I saw in other stack overflow posts that this touchables from this library had issues. And in my case it did not work either.

Comment: It worked. But I wonder,what is the reason behind that ?

Comment: this works on me thanks. In my case, there is touchable components hidden from the screen, and when it appears, it wont pressable...
then I use TouchableOpacity from gesture-handler and everything just works, do you know why?